# ABAP: Glossary of terms

Tags: translation, abap

I try to find a glossary of abap related terms.

I tried this page, but it failed with "sapterm.com:50026 not reachable" http://www.sapterm.com/

I tried this page to search for "data element" but the search has a nice progress bar, but after waiting for some minutes, still no result: https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/GLOSSARY/?q=data%20element

For me it is important to have the matching English and German terms, since we have international customers.

I don't want to translate these terms myself, and using a online dictionaries return false results often.

I would like to know the official translation which is used by sap itself.

Comment: Why don't you just log in to the SAP system chossing language DE and see matching descriptions for yourself?

Comment: @Jagger yes, this should work, for many cases. It might not work for all cases like "logical unit of work" (LUW). Is there a way to find this term in a german sap-gui?

Comment: Transaction `ABAPDOCU` and then search for `logical unit of work`. Once found, look at the tree path. Login in once again in German and start `ABAPDOCU` as well, follow the path found in English version and there you are. In this case however `logical unit of work` is in German `Datenbank-LUW`. XD

Comment: @Jagger if you post your comment as answer, then I can upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction code SAPTERM should be more comfortable, not sure how up to date it is but it is worth a try:

[image]

Comment: I have been working with SAP for years and still was not aware that there is such a transaction. Nice answer! Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I've discovered this only a couple of months ago myself, very handy especially when translating business terms :)

Comment: An online version has the great benefit that I can send a link to a term via mail or put it into the text of a web based issue tracking system. Is there an online version available, too?

Comment: See answer below by @Suncatcher, but the URL is static.

Answer (score 1):

Simply log in with your SAP user and select your language explicitely as German (DE)

or

1. If you want to browse the technical documentation on ABAP then run the transaction `ABAPDOCU` once logged in and search for your term.
2. Once found, remember the path in the navigator tree on the left hand side.
3. Log in in a separate window but this time in German (DE) and run the transaction `ABAPDOCU`. Follow the path you got once searching for the English term.

Voilà! You have found the German term for your wanted English term.

Answer (score 1):

The official ABAP documentation always contained an accurate glossary of terms, for all ABAP versions.

Here are the links to the glossary of ABAP 7.52 (with approximately 1.300 entries) :

- [English](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_glossary.htm)
- [German](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/de-DE/index.htm?file=abenabap_glossary.htm)

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, comment added to explain the links.

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL is

[sapterm.com:50026/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/sterm_webaccess?sap-client=000](http://sapterm.com:50026/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/sterm_webaccess?sap-client=000)

Comment: I can't open the URL.

Comment: Opened [like a charm](https://imgur.com/cvUsEJc) for me, the problem is on your side...

Comment: I tried this on a internet server: `guettli@hz1:~$ curl http://sapterm.com:50026/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/sterm_webaccess?sap-client=000` result: 
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>500 SAP Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>500 SAP Internal Server Error</H1>
ERROR: This browser is not supported (termination: ERROR_MESSAGE_STATE)<P>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: `This browser is not supported` ya?  Change the browser:) For example to Chrome 72

Comment: Unlikely this glossary is adapted for opening via curl, you want too much from SAP, haha

Comment: I guess this page won't get indexed by google and other search engines, too. Nobody will notice that this page exists. Haha